# How to send model data from one controller to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult BookingStep1()
        {
           return View(new BookingMainApplicantInfo());
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BookingStep1(BookingMainApplicantInfo mainApplicant)
        {
          return View(mainApplicant);
        }

  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult BookingStep12()
        {
           //how to fetch data from above step 2 to here
            return View();
        }
```

Scenario is to send member data to next step i.e the next actionresult where I will calculate the invoice and give payment option.

Should I use session or should I save it to db?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use session or should I save it to db?

You should keep these as last options. Following are my suggestions.

1. TempData
2. RedirectToAction

**TempData** - This is just like a `DataReader`. Once the key is read the data will be become null. In case you still want to persist the data after reading it you can use the code like below

```
TempData.Alive()
```

`Alive` function will persist the data even after the `TempData` for the particular key is read.

**RedirectToAction** - In this approach you can set the Query String Values in the parameter list. Below is the sample code.

```
return RedirectToAction( "Action Name", 
                             new RouteValueDictionary
                             ( 
                                   new 
                                   { 
                                        controller = controllerName, 
                                        action = "Action Name", 
                                        QueryStringKey = "Query String Value" 
                                   } 
                             )    
                       );
```

Comment: But I have to send long list of model data, is it ok to send so much data via querystring or tempdata?

Comment: In this scenario you should use TempData.